# Installing vlc on rhel6

Tags: rhel, vlc

As my first step downloaded vlc-2.1.5.tar.xz. after extracting ran "./configure" there comes this monster

"configure: error: Could not find lua. Lua is needed for some interfaces (rc, telnet, http) as well as many other custom scripts. Use --disable-lua to ignore this error."

unable to figure out what went wrong ? Even a hint is appreciated :)

Comment: The error says it all. lua is a separate tool - and as such requires installation if you want to make use of it (there is probably a package you can install from yum). If you don't think you need lua with vlc, then just run `configure --without-lua`.

Comment: i have to work on a offline system. Even disabling the "lua" is followed by multiple Errors

Answer (score 0):

Run `lua -v` to ensure that you have installed it.

Also you need Lua header/library files `lua-devel`: [link](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=lua-devel)

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925363/compiling-vlc-on-linux-error-couldnt-find-lua)

Comment: lua -v
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio Its already present

Comment: Then you need `lua-devel` package

Comment: I've downloaded the following "lua-devel-5.1.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm,lua-devel-5.1.4-1.el6.i686.rpm" Still the Same error as above :(

Comment: Can you try lua-devel-5.1.4-4.1.el6.i686.rpm, lua-devel-5.1.4-4.1.el6.x86_64.rpm ?

Comment: Hey it worked :) But gave room for a new one  --------------checking for AVCODEC... no
configure: error: No package 'libavcodec' found
No package 'libavutil' found. Pass --disable-avcodec to ignore this error.

Comment: Try to add `--prefix=/usr` to the configure line. If you don't have it, install [link](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libavcodec&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=)

Comment: @Ksk have you resolved the issue?

Comment: Yes Finally i'm able to install Vlc . By running "./configure --skip-broken" which then provides us a list of skipped dependencies. Then i've taken time to install them manually one after the other.